# Identify This Date Format (Timestamp)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, timestamp

I'm trying to identify how this date is being formatted. I'm using jQuery datepicker inside Tablesorter inside Wordpress. The Dates go as so:

```
Actual Date - October 13 2013
Datpicker   - 1381640400000
Str To Time - 1381622400

Actual Date - Setpember 11 2013
Datpicker   - 1378875600000
Str To Time - 1378857600

Actual Date - Setpember 24 2013
Datpicker   - 1379998800000
Str To Time - 1379980800
```

I'm converting the Wordpress Post Date to Timestamp so the Datepicker in my Tablesorter can sort on that timestamp, but StrToTime returns a slightly off time compared to the datepicker.

My Wordpress Time Formats Are:

```
UTC+0
September 10, 2013
7:22 pm
Monday
```

Does anybody recognize the timestamp above / know how I can get that exact stamp?

**EDIT**

When I divided by 1000 it almost worked out, but still slight differences. When I use date() though I do get the same day - so where are the slight differences coming from and how do I make up for them or get around them?

Comment: "slightly off" ?? By around 30 years or so !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript returns timestamps in milliseconds. PHP returns timestamps in seconds.

Divide/multiple by 1,000 to get the appropriate timestamp between PHP/JavaScript.

Comment: While you are right, the timestamps are still off by a little. `13799988` and `13799808` using the last date in my above example.

Comment: Note that JavaScript is a client side technology and therefore gets the date/time from the clients system which may not match your server. This could account for the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The strtotime() function is simply leaving off the extra '0's at the end that the DatePicker includes.

Those numbers are the UNIX timestamp or seconds since the EPOCH. Divide the value by 1000 to get a correct timestamp.

You can convert that to a readable format that is SQL friendly like this:

```
$datePickerValue = 1379998800000/1000;
$date = date("y-m-d H:m:s", $datePickerValue);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`timeFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) option in the DatePicker and set it to use seconds instead of milliseconds:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  //altField: "#alternate",
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
});
});
```

But you shouldn't trust the client's timezone. There is no single reliable way and there will never be. Always use a server-side solution for handling time / date stuff. Make  use of the PHP's built-in functions and [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class.